# How to solve a equation with floor in it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to do everything I could, but I don't know what to do with that floor.

$58 = y\cdot\left[\frac{80}{y}\right]$

Where $[x]$ is floor function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

So, $\frac{58}y= \left[\frac{80}{y}\right] $ which is an integer

$\implies y$ must divide $58$

Comment: Ok, now I know how to do my homework, but in freetime I'm a programmer and now I thought about a way of using it in my program,  but I would need to do something to have y only on one side. Is it possible? If not then i'm gonna find diffrent way of doing it.

Comment: I'm currently thinking about a way of calculating b from 
a mod b = c
I have a and c. I think that this would fit it, because if a would be equal 80 and c would be 22, then you would get:
80 mod i = 22, so

80 - i*[80/i] = 22, so

22-80 = -i*[80/i], so

58 = i*[80/i]

Comment: @10HeadLess, you iterate for the values of $y,$ such that $y\cdot \left[\frac{80}{y}\right]=58$ Clearly, $-58\le y \le 58$ Which programing language  you follow?

Comment: i am using java

Comment: void process() {
  for (int y = -100; y < 100; y++) {
   if (y != 0) {
    double floor = Math.floor(80 / y);
    if (y * (int) floor == 58) {
     System.out.println(y);
    }
   }
  }
 }

Comment: thank you, you are awesome